# EF lazy loading: EntityType does not declare a navigation property with the name

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have a classes structure something like that:

```
public class Customer{
         public AgreementDetails Agreement { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class AgreementDetails{
    public int SalesPersonId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SalesPersonId")]
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual SalesPerson Sales { get; set; }
}
public class SalesPerson
{
...
}
```

When I'm displaying the list of customers, i'm calling Sales property to disaply sales person details but property is null, usually for navigating properties this can be avoid using .Include method but it doesn't work in my case, so the query is

```
List<Customer> res = db.Customers.Include(c=>c.Agreement.Sales).ToList();
```

The exception is:

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType
>   'CodeFirstNamespace.Customer' does not declare a navigation property
>   with the name 'Agreement'.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: **complex types shouldn't contain navigation properties (as well as foreign keys).**